# how can i display comments below the respective post in the home page

Tags: django, django-models, django-comments

i want to implement something like fb does like displaying all the respective comments below their respective posts in home page
*model.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'profile_image')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User ,on_delete = 'models.CASCADE')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = 'models.CASCADE')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null = True, on_delete = 'models.CASCADE')
    comment = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

***views.py***

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect,get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from home.forms import HomeForm,Home,CommentForm
from home.models import Post ,ImagePost,Comment


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        form1 = CommentForm()
        posts = Post.objects.filter(user = request.user).order_by('-created')
        comments = Comment.objects.all()
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        args = {
            'form': form, 'posts': posts, 'users': users, 'form1':form1,
            'comments':comments,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form1 = CommentForm()
        text = ''
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = HomeForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():

                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.user = request.user
                post.save()
                text = form.cleaned_data['post']
                form = HomeForm()
                form1 = CommentForm()
                return redirect('home:home')
    def cmnt(self , request):
        text = ''
        form1 = CommentForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form1 = CommentForm(request.POST,post.id)
            if form.is_valid():
                comment = form.save(commit = False)
                comment.user = request.user
                comment.post = request.post
                comment.save()
                text = form.cleaned_data['comment']
                form1 = CommentForm()
                form = HomeForm()
                return redirect('home:home')

            args = {'form': form, 'text': text , 'form1':form1}
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

***home.html***

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{%  load static %}

{% block body %} 
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2>Home</h2>
        <form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" type = 'file'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.post }}
            {{ form.image }}
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <h2>{{ text }}</h2>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <h1>{{ post.post }}</h1>
            <br>
            <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" width = 240 >
            <p>Posted by {{ post.user.get_full_name }} on {{ post.created }}</p>
        <form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" type = 'file'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form1.comment }}
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

            {% for comment in comments %}
            {% if comment.post_id == post.id %}
            <h1>{{ comment.comment }}</h1>
            <p>commented by {{ comment.user.get_full_name }} on {{ comment.created }}</p>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

[using my django admin i am able to assign comments to the respective post and display it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpVnJ.png)

i am finding difficulty to assign comment's post_id with the post id

***urls.py***

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from django.urls import path
from .import views
from home.views import HomeView


app_name = "home"
urlpatterns = [
     path('',HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

first, change Comment model like this:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = 'models.CASCADE')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null = True, on_delete = 'models.CASCADE')
    text = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

second, you don't need return list of comment to the template. do like this in your template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{%  load static %}

{% block body %} 
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8">

        <h2>{{ text }}</h2>
        {% for post in posts %}
           <h1>{{ post.post }}</h1>
           <br>
           <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" width = 240 >
           <p>Posted by {{ post.user.get_full_name }} on {{ post.created }}</p>

            {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}

                <h1>{{ comment.text }}</h1>
                <p>commented by {{ comment.user.get_full_name }} on {{ comment.created }}</p>            
           {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

</div>
```

Comment: by making the changes i am able to display comments but, i want logged in users to add comments for that i made a comment form(u can see it in home.html form1 is COMMENTS FORM)  [link](http://dpaste.com/28H8TB9) i get this error

Comment: If my answer is correct, check it out and put this question in another post so that others can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here

```
form1 = CommentForm(request.POST,Post.id)
```

p in post should be lowercase

```
form1 = CommentForm(request.POST,post.id)
```

you have two POST forms. for every post write separate view. you accept both form in just one view. it's incorrect.

Comment: after editing my **views.py**  [link](http://dpaste.com/07MHGW7) i get this error

Answer (score 0):

```
def post(self, request):
    form1 = CommentForm()
    text = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HomeForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
            form = HomeForm()
            form1 = CommentForm()
            return redirect('home:home')
```

in post method you redirect to home page. it means, you call get method of HomeView.

in get method, you need below variable in context dict

```
args = {
        'form': form, 'posts': posts, 'users': users, 'form1':form1,
        'comments':comments,
    }
```

but you don't set value for these variables.